# not bound port listening

Tags: networking, netstat

Here is what netstat shows:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       User       Inode      PID/Program name    

tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          17668      -    

udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                           0          22969      -
```

I do not have any PID nor program name related to local port 631 and 68; how do I stop these ports from listening? Does this allow tunnels to be created or is this could be the result of previously created tunnels?

regarding ipv6:

```
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      0          17667      -
```

I do not want Ipv6, but doing the following does not change what I see above :

```
echo 'net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1' >> /etc/sysctl.conf

echo 'net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1' >> /etc/sysctl.conf

echo 'net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1' >> /etc/sysctl.conf

sysctl -p
```

thankx in advance folks!

Comment: To get process names/PIDs, you need to run `netstat` as root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UDP/68 is easy: That's the DHCP client

TCP/631 is no problem as well:

- First of all it's bound to localhost only, so not reachable from the network
- Secondly it's most likely CUPS (which you can check by stopping it), so an easy but propable explanation exists as well.

Comment: -@Eugen: how would it appear if it was reachable from outside network?

Comment: See the "Local Address" column: 127.x.x.x (most often 127.0.0.1) is the loopback network, it provides a network connection only from a host to itself.